# "Failed to map the path '/App_GlobalResources/'" when interfacing two web applications via AppDomains

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis-8

I'm creating an interface between two separate web applications with entirely separate code bases so I can reuse logic from one application in another. I do this by creating a second AppDomain within the parent application into which I load the second web application, and use a proxy to communicate between the two.

This is working, but only if I use a specific application pool, specifically if I use the built in '.NET 4.5 Classic' app pool. If I use a manually created app pool I receive the error  'Failed to map the path '/App_GlobalResources/'.

The thing is, I can't see any practical difference between how the app pools are currently configured. I also don't think it's a permissions issue because this still occurs even if I run both app pools under the same administrator account.

Here's the XML for the application pool which works, from applicationHost.config:

```
    <add name=".NET v4.5 Classic" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" managedPipelineMode="Classic">
        <processModel identityType="SpecificUser" userName="{my username}" password="{my encoded password}" />
    </add>
```

Here is the XML for the application pool which doesn't work:

```
    <add name="{app pool name, removed as it contains the client name}" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" managedPipelineMode="Classic">
        <processModel identityType="SpecificUser" userName="{my username}" password="{my encoded password}" />
    </add>
```

Here's the app pool defaults, even though I don't think this should make a difference:

```
    <applicationPoolDefaults managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0">
        <processModel identityType="ApplicationPoolIdentity" loadUserProfile="true" setProfileEnvironment="false" />
    </applicationPoolDefaults>
```

Is there anything I'm missing in terms of application pool configuration? Or anything else I should configure and/or investigate?

EDIT 2014/07/08:

Here's a self contained example to reproduce the issue:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7mtq3lFmDqyd1VZZ1ZCdHFsa1U/edit?usp=sharing

To set this up you must set up WebApplication1 as localhost/WebApplication1 and WebApplication4 as localhost/WebApplication4.

You should also change the hard coded path in Default.aspx.cs to point to the root of WebApplciation4 on your machine.

You may need to try a few different app pools to reproduce the error. I'd suggest setting up a new one for .NET 4 in classic mode.

EDIT 2014/07/12

Here's a stack trace for the error:

```
[InvalidOperationException: Failed to map the path '/Mvc/App_GlobalResources/'.]
   System.Web.Configuration.ProcessHostConfigUtils.MapPathActual(String siteName, VirtualPath path) +244
   System.Web.Configuration.ProcessHostServerConfig.System.Web.Configuration.IServerConfig.MapPath(IApplicationHost appHost, VirtualPath path) +34
   System.Web.Hosting.MapPathBasedVirtualPathEnumerator..ctor(VirtualPath virtualPath, RequestedEntryType requestedEntryType) +285
   System.Web.Hosting.MapPathBasedVirtualPathCollection.System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() +43
   System.Web.Compilation.CodeDirectoryCompiler.ProcessDirectoryRecursive(VirtualDirectory vdir, Boolean topLevel) +321
   System.Web.Compilation.CodeDirectoryCompiler.GetCodeDirectoryAssembly(VirtualPath virtualDir, CodeDirectoryType dirType, String assemblyName, StringSet excludedSubdirectories, Boolean isDirectoryAllowed) +670
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileCodeDirectory(VirtualPath virtualDir, CodeDirectoryType dirType, String assemblyName, StringSet excludedSubdirectories) +175
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled() +508
```

Comment: Please post some code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @MichaelLiu I've added a link to a project which reproduces the issue.

Comment: have you tried changing managedPipelineMode to integrated ??

Comment: @Alok Yes, but unfortunately this app needs to run in classic mode for a couple of reasons.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue on my Windows 8.1 machine. Does the error have a stack trace?

Comment: @MichaelLiu Hi Michael, I've added a stack trace to the question.

Comment: Are you sure there is nothing different between the two app pools except their names?

Comment: @Alireza as far as I can see there's no difference, but that's the reason for the question as there must be a difference, either in the app pool itself or in something related

Comment: Strangely I can't download the example's whole ZIP file

Comment: I'm now trying to start the projects. But at the first look just curious about the virtual path in this call: `_proxy = (Proxy)ApplicationHost.CreateApplicationHost(typeof(Proxy), "/", @"C:\Users...");` shouldn't the second parameter be something like `/WebApplication4`?

Comment: @Ian Newton still nothing?

Comment: @Alireza Hi, no changing that parameter doesn't seem to help.

Comment: FYI I've found that the problem only seems to occur if you don't have a website named 'Default Web Site'

Comment: The web site's name has absolutely nothing to do with anything. It is just a title. Which port is the other website bound to? Still 80?

Comment: @Alireza Untrue. Look at UnsafeIISMethods.MgdMapPathDirect, and in particular the siteName argument: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/xsp/system/Web/Hosting/IISUnsafeMethods.cs

Comment: @Alireza Also, there is no other website. There's two sets of website code but they're hosted within the same actual website.

Comment: I'm actually worried about that `/Mvc` at the virtual path's start. Why is it trying to resolve that? is it your actual application name?

Comment: Oh, and by 'Other web site' I meant the web site that is hosting your web application, the actual one which is not 'Default web site'. you said "the problem only seems to occur if you don't have a website named 'Default Web Site'" but you do have at least a web site. What's its configuration?

Comment: @Alireza /MVC is the name of the child application in IIS, as it is also set up as a child application. I've tried it with / as well which doesn't solve the problem. The website setup in IIS is very standard, with the only really difference from a standard setup is that it's using Classic mode. So you're aware I think I've figured it out now so will be posting my solution and explanation in the next few hours.

Comment: I will appreciate that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the app pool errors were a slight red herring, as neither app pool was really working correctly but only one was throwing an error.

When creating a new application host via `ApplicationHost.CreateApplicationHost` the framework will use a `SimpleApplicationHost` instead of `ISAPIApplicationHost`, which is typically used when hosting  websites within IIS. `SimpleApplicationHost` is *very* simple, and defaults the name of the website to 'Default Web Site' and the ID of the site to 1. You may notice that these values match the default website within IIS, which means that while one app pool appeared to work it was actually mapping its path against the default web site, which means virtual paths were resolving to absolute paths like 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Mvc\App_GlobalResources', which was incorrect anyway.

The fix is to change the `VirtualPathProvider` from the default `MapPathBasedVirtualPathProvider` to a custom provider which maps based on the already known values of the child app. I was already doing this in fact, but I was doing it too late in the process as the error is thrown during the initialization of the new application host, which is part of the `ApplicationHost.CreateHost` call. At this point it seemed all hope was lost...

Then, I found out about little known feature of ASP.NET, `PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute`. This is actually used by the initialisation of the ASP.NET `BuildManager`, which is used by `ApplicationHost.CreateHost`. By implementing this attribute I was able to replace the virtual path provider before it was used by the initialisation code.

I haven't actually found out the reason why one app pool seemed to work while another didn't, but I suspect it's either a concurrency issue within webengine4.dll, or an issue with the site name being passed into WebEngine4.dll.